# SWIFT passing parameter from VC to UIView drives me nuts

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to get this done since yesterday, but no approach was successful. While I have learned a lot, some fundamentals still seem to be missing.

I have a view controller that shall contain several subviews in a stack. Each subview shall use the same UIView class in a separate swift file. However, for each subview I want to pass a position ID to the UIView class. The controller and the subviews are created with the storyboard.

So my latest and best approach is

```
class SpatialViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet var redSquare: SpatialProblemView!
   @IBOutlet var blueSquare: SpatialProblemView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   
       redSquare = SpatialProblemView(subviewName: "red")
       blueSquare = SpatialProblemView(subviewName: "blue")
   //  redSquare.subviewName = "red"
    
       self.view.addSubview(redSquare)
   }
}
```

and

```
class SpatialProblemView: UIView {
   var subviewName: String

   init(subviewName: String){
       self.subviewName = subviewName
       super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
   }
   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   }
}
```

I have also tried to code the UIView with this

```
required init(subviewName: String) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    self.subviewName = subviewName
    self.setup()
}

required override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()

func setup() {
    if subviewName == "red" {
        print ("red")
    }
}
```

but that seem further apart from a running code. With the **upper** UIView definition I receive the error **Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented** in the console and **Property 'self.subviewName' not initialized at super.init call** inline within the editor. Both relate to

```
super.init(coder: aDecoder)
```

I have looked for other posts here with this error message, but none I saw helped me. Any help is highly appreciated :-)

Comment: `SpatialProblemView(subviewName: "red")`: You are creating a new instance. Previously it was referencing `@IBOutlet var blueSquare: SpatialProblemView!` in Storyboard, but not anymore. Why don't you do just `blueSquare.subviewName = "blue"`? as you did in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make it optional

```
 var subviewName: String?
```

and if you make them as outlets then you shouldn't assign a new instance here

```
SpatialProblemView(subviewName: "red")
```

just assign the property

```
redSquare.subviewName = "red"
```

Comment: Wow, that did the job. Just that simple. Could you maybe please explain, how the error message relates to making the variable optional

Comment: the error says that a non optional variable isn't initiated upon creating the instance from storyboard  hence the crash making it optional will allow null ability until you assign them in `viewDidLoad` btw search for `IBInspectable / IBDesignable` to set those properties from IB